# eof(), bad(), good() functions aren't detected by autocomplete

Tags: c++, autocomplete, qt-creator

This code block:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/), compiles and runs well, but the **good()** function isn't recognized by my IDE (Qt) when I try to write it by hand and use autocomplete. Can anyone tell me why?

Thank you

P.S.   I use the mingw compiler, if that helps.

Comment: I'd guess working as intended. They just choosed to disable it for words with low character count - which sounds reasonable. There will be too many alternatives if you just type 'g' or 'go'

Comment: @typ1232 Qt Creator also uses 'triggers' to fire the autocomplete system, so as soon as the OP hit "." it should offer every method/member of `myfile` - but it doesn't offer the `std::basic_ios` state methods. @GeorgeStocker It is not acceptable to close a question without any explanation, especially when there's clearly nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Do your really have difficulty figuring out what is being asked here? It seems perfectly clear to me. He wants to know why the autocomplete feature isn't working for certain functions in Qt-Creator.  And it's not too much of a leap in logic to figure out that he would also like to know how he could remedy that situation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It was flagged as a 'troll question'.  Unfortunately, there is no 'troll question' close reason.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow,  I don't see where my question is marked as closed or flagged. But thank you @BenjaminLindley for supporting me:) Well, can I do something to "remedy this situation" ?

Comment: This could be considered a feature - the idiomatic use is `while (myfile)`, or in this case actually `while (getline(myfile, line))`  (because you will output a line too many otherwise). I don't think I've ever used `good`, `bad`, or `eof` for anything except for causing problems.