# std vector.data return void

Tags: c++, vector

I required your help for a very strange behaviour that I can't understand.

I wrote a simple usage of vector.data :

```
    void* ptr = NULL; // really initialized somewhere else
    bool* boolPtr = NULL;
    boolPtr = ((std::vector<bool>*)ptr)->data();
```

and when I compile (with -std=c++17) I got the error

```
void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

I try a lot a things but it seems that each time I call, from a casted vector (from void*), the data() method return a void instead of a bool*.

What did I miss ?

Comment: A `vector<bool>` is a special type of vector and there is no API to get at the underlying buffer.

Comment: Whenever you do a C-style cast in C++ (like you do with `(std::vector<bool>*)ptr`) you should take that as a sign that you're doing something *wrong!* A vector is *not* equivalent to an array, other than some of the vectors operations mimic that of an array. To make matters worse, `std::vector<bool>` is a *specialization* that is unlike any other `std::vector`.

Comment: Duplicate? [What happens when you call data() on a std::vector<bool>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568986/what-happens-when-you-call-data-on-a-stdvectorbool)

Comment: Also, the way a programmer attempts to figure out a problem like this is to break up that line of code into multiple statements.  `((std::vector<bool>*)ptr)->data();` -- Is it the cast that is the issue?  Is it the call to `data()` that is the issue?  You don't know, because you are doing multiple things on one line.  What you should have done is do the cast and assign it to a variable -- see if the compiler is issuing a warning/error for that line.  Then take that variable and use it to call `data()`, etc.  I see too many programmers munge things on one line trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good advice in general. Unfortunately not just for any case with a C-style cast, as that tells the compiler "Hands off, I know what I'm doing!" even if that's not true (as is the case here).

Comment: For such cases, I have a `struct Bool { bool value; }` at hand. `std::vector<Bool>` behaves as `std::vector` for every other type (except `bool`). (I gave it a conversion operator to `bool` (among other methods) so that it can be conveniently used like a `bool`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<bool>` is not a proper vector. As weird as that sounds, that's the way it is. It can't give you a pointer to its internal bool array, because it doesn't have one, since it stores the values packed into single bits.

Comment: Holy crap, thank for your help, I will try with comme classic type so :)

Comment: And obviously it works with other primitive type ...